# Can't Get New Instance Of RT To Start

Tags: fastcgi, suexec, request-tracker

I am trying to transplant an instance of RT 4.0.1 (with local code customization) from a CentOS 4 server to a CentOS 6 server.

My problem appears to be that I can't get the fastcgi script to start.

When apache starts, it gives this error:

```
[Mon Mar 25 12:37:37 2013] [warn] FastCGI: server "/opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server.fcgi" (uid 48, gid 48) restarted (pid 1504) suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
[Mon Mar 25 12:37:37 2013] [warn] FastCGI: server "/opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server.fcgi" (pid 1504) terminated by calling exit with status '107'
[Mon Mar 25 12:37:38 2013] [warn] FastCGI: server "/opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server.fcgi" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
```

The contents of suexec.log:

```
[2013-03-25 12:37:37]: uid: (apache/apache) gid: (apache/apache) cmd: rt-server.fcgi
[2013-03-25 12:37:37]: cannot run as forbidden uid (48/rt-server.fcgi)
```

The suexec.log implies I need to either

- tell suexec it is permitted to run the fastcgi script as apache (which is what seems to be happening on the C4 system); or
- figure out how tell suexec to run the fastcgi script as a different user

My google-fu is weak today, I cannot find an answer to either question.

The contents of the site definition:

```
FastCgiServer /opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server.fcgi -processes 5 -idle-timeout 180

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName arrtee.$MYDOMAIN

   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   # Pass through requests to display images
   Alias /NoAuth/images/ /opt/rt4/share/html/NoAuth/images/
   ScriptAlias / /opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server.fcgi/

   DocumentRoot "/opt/rt4/share/html"
   <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler fastcgi-script fcgi
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can run the fastgcgi-script as root, and it works.  (After which point I change the ownership and groupmembership on the entire /opt/rt4 tree back to apache:apache.)

I've even removed the whole /opt/rt4 tree and tried to re-install from source, and that it still doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no cure for a problem like asking a quesiton in a public forum.

In my case, on the CentOS 6 server, there is a directive in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fastcgi.conf`:

```
# wrap all fastcgi script calls in suexec
FastCgiWrapper On
```

Comment out the second line, and it works, presumably by disabling the suexec security.  Which in the long run is probably the wrong solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention how you installed fastcgi, but there is note in the [web deployment docs](http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/latest/web_deployment.html#mod_fastcgi) that some distributions also need:

```
FastCgiIpcDir /tmp
```

Many users have also had luck with mod_fcgid, which is available as a package via [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

SELinux settings can also sometimes cause permission problems and require special settings if you want to leave it fully enabled.

Comment: In my case, the fastcgi was the default load with CentOS 6.  And I did mess around with the FastCgiIpcDir setting thinking that was the permissions problem.